# Why did this \heightof and \widthof stop working?

Tags: tikz-pgf

The following has worked for me for quite some time.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}            
\geometry{letterpaper}                 
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}   

\usepackage{tikz, pgf, calc}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix, shapes, positioning, calc, decorations.pathreplacing, shapes.geometric, arrows}

\newcounter{Day}

\newcounter{pt}[Day]    % CORRECTNESS POINTS FOR HW RUBRICS
\newcommand{\pt}[2]     % NUMBER OF POINTS, ITEM IN STARBURST
    {#2\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
        \node (A) [starburst, 
            draw = red, opacity = .8, 
            fill = red!20, fill opacity = .2, 
            xshift = -.5*\widthof{#2},
            yshift = .5*\heightof{#2}
            ]
            {\phantom{#2}};
        \node (B) at (current page.west) {};
        \path let \p1 = (A), \p2 = (B) in node [draw = red, 
            color = red] at (\x2+.625in,\y1) {#1 pt(s)};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \addtocounter{pt}{#1}
    }

\begin{document}

\pt{1}{lorem}

\end{document}
```

Recently, I updated several packages with MikTeX 2.9.  Below is a screenshot of the packages that were updated.

[image: Updated packages]

Since the updates, the `\widthof` and `\heightof` commands are causing errors.  If I change the `xshift` and `yshift` to something else, everything compiles just fine (but isn't the way I want my command to work).  I have two questions:

1. Why did this work before and not now?
2. How can I change my code to make it work correctly again?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: There were some changes in `pgf` that removed support for `\widthof`, _etc._: I'll see if I can track it down

Comment: They come from the calc package, which is sometimes called by other packages.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`\widthof` and `\heightof` (`\depthof`, `\totalheightof`, `\maxof`, `\minof`) are features of package `calc` and enhance the mathematical expressions in `\setlength`, `\addtolength`, `\setcounter`, and `\addtocounter`. Package `pgf` comes with its own math engines. I have not found `\widthof` in the TikZ manual. Therefore, I conclude that these measurement macros are not officially supported.
On the other hand, `pgfmathparser.code.tex` contains:

```
% Stuff for calc compatiability.
\let\real=\pgfmath@calc@real
\let\minof=\pgfmath@calc@minof
\let\maxof=\pgfmath@calc@maxof
\let\ratio=\pgfmath@calc@ratio
\let\widthof=\pgfmath@calc@widthof
\let\heightof=\pgfmath@calc@heightof
\let\depthof=\pgfmath@calc@depthof

[...]

% Stuff for compatability with the calc package.
%
\def\pgfmath@calc@real#1{#1}
\def\pgfmath@calc@minof#1#2{min(#1,#2)}
\def\pgfmath@calc@maxof#1#2{max(#1,#2)}
\def\pgfmath@calc@ratio#1#2{#1/#2}
\def\pgfmath@calc@widthof#1{width("#1")}
\def\pgfmath@calc@heightof#1{height("#1")}
\def\pgfmath@calc@depthof#1{depth("#1")}
```

The example works with `pgf` functions `width` and `height`:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\geometry{letterpaper}
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}

\usepackage{tikz, pgf, calc}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix, shapes, positioning, calc,
  decorations.pathreplacing, shapes.geometric, arrows}

\newcounter{Day}

\newcounter{pt}[Day]    % CORRECTNESS POINTS FOR HW RUBRICS
\newcommand{\pt}[2]     % NUMBER OF POINTS, ITEM IN STARBURST
    {#2 \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
        \node (A) [starburst,
            draw = red, opacity = .8,
            fill = red!20, fill opacity = .2,
            xshift = {-.5*width("#2")}, % \widthof{#2},
            yshift = {.5*height("#2")}, % \heightof{#2}
            ]
            {\phantom{#2}};
        \node (B) at (current page.west) {};
        \path let \p1 = (A), \p2 = (B) in node [draw = red,
            color = red] at (\x2+.625in,\y1) {#1 pt(s)};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \addtocounter{pt}{#1}
    }

\begin{document}

\pt{1}{lorem}

\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Thus, a workaround is found.

---

BTW, the code in the example seems unnecessarily complicate (or I do not have understood the purposes of some constructions). For example, the text is not put in the node, but before, separated by a space. The latter is not considered in the calculations, moving the starburst node away from the center of the text.

A simplified version:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}

\newcounter{Day}
\newcounter{pt}[Day]

\newcommand*{\pt}[2]{%
  \textcolor{red}{\fbox{#1 pt(s)}}\quad
  \tikz[baseline=(A.base)]\node (A) [
    starburst,
    draw=red,
    fill=red!20,
    fill opacity=.2,
    text opacity=1,
  ] {#2};%
  \addtocounter{pt}{#1}%
}

\begin{document}

\pt{1}{lorem}

\pt{1}{$\pi$}

\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: This is working great for the example `\pt{1}{lorem}`, but now it no longer works for something like `\pt{1}{$\pi$}` (it used to when `\widthof` and `\heightof` were still working for me).  Is there a way to make this work with `width` and `height`?

Comment: @Charlie `\pt{1}{$\pi$}` works for me, using `width("#2")` in the definition as in the example of the answer.

Comment: I'm sorry, you're right, that does work.  (I assumed that any math in the second input would result in an error, but that's not so.)  This is actually what just threw an error for me: `\pt{1}{$[-1,1]$}`.  Very weird.  Why would `\pt{1}{$\pi$}` work and `\pt{1}{$[-1,1]$}` not?

Comment: @Charlie The parser for the optional argument of the node thinks, the closing square bracket inside `width("...")` is the end of the options. Adding curly braces around the value should fix the issue, see the updated answer code.

Comment: I am not using your packages, but: I have discovered that if I first create a `\newlength{whatever}` then later `\setlength\whatever{\widthof{text}}` it works in situations that otherwise fail. I do not know why. Some time ago, I could directly use `\widthof` without first creating a length.