# TikZ style to set scale relative to letter height using \settoheight

Tags: tikz-pgf, fonts

I'd like to have a style to make my drawings exactly as tall as a capital letter, in order to draw things in a line of text, even if the drawing command is used in a block of text with a different font or size (say, a footnote or the table of contents). I'd like to avoid metrics like `em` or `ex` because their definition relative to capital letters is not consistent across fonts (see [What is the local height of a capital letter?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/275374/12440)).

Getting the height of a capital letter works with `\settoheight`, but not inside `\tikz[<styles>]`. I guess that is because the TikZ parser sets the font to nullfont or something like that. Wrapping the whole `\tikz` command in a macro works, but having an actual TikZ style to achieve the same would be nicer. Can this be done?

[image: Output of the example code]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newdimen\myLetterHeight
\tikzset{
    scale to letter height/.code={%
        \settoheight{\myLetterHeight}{#1}%
        \pgfkeysalso{/tikz/x=\myLetterHeight, /tikz/y=\myLetterHeight, baseline=0pt}%
    },
}
\newcommand*{\TikzScaleToLetterHeight}[2][X]{\begingroup%
    \settoheight{\myLetterHeight}{#1}%
    \pgfkeysalso{/tikz/x=\myLetterHeight, /tikz/y=\myLetterHeight, /tikz/baseline=0pt}%
    #2%
\endgroup}

\begin{document}
WITH KEY: \tikz[scale to letter height=X]
    \draw rectangle (1,1) node[right] {\the\myLetterHeight};

WITH MACRO: \TikzScaleToLetterHeight[X]{\tikz
    \draw rectangle (1,1) node[right] {\the\myLetterHeight};}

{\Large Large: \TikzScaleToLetterHeight[X]{\tikz
    \draw rectangle (1,1) node[right] {\the\myLetterHeight};}}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this code for the style definition.

[image: A]

Measures the height of a letter following the answer in [height of a box using `pgf`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/353904/161015) where it explains that, for `pgf`, `height("#1")` is the equivalent of `\heightof{#1}` from the `calc` package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newdimen\myLetterHeight

\newlength{\NewLetterHeight}

\tikzset{%
     letterheight/.code={%              
        \pgfmathparse{height("#1")} %From https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/353904/161015
        \setlength{\NewLetterHeight}{\pgfmathresult pt}
        \pgfkeysalso{/tikz/x=\the\NewLetterHeight, /tikz/y=\the\NewLetterHeight, baseline=0pt}%
    },
}
\newcommand*{\TikzScaleToLetterHeight}[2][X]{\begingroup%
    \settoheight{\myLetterHeight}{#1}%
    \pgfkeysalso{/tikz/x=\myLetterHeight, /tikz/y=\myLetterHeight, /tikz/baseline=0pt}%
    #2%
    \endgroup}

\begin{document}
    WITH KEY: \tikz[letterheight=X]
    \draw rectangle (1,1) node[right] {\the\NewLetterHeight};
    
    WITH MACRO: \TikzScaleToLetterHeight[X]{\tikz
        \draw rectangle (1,1) node[right] {\the\myLetterHeight};}
    
    {\Large Large: \TikzScaleToLetterHeight[X]{\tikz
            \draw rectangle (1,1) node[right] {\the\myLetterHeight};}}
\end{document}
```

**Best solution.** The style definition could be further simplified.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}   

\tikzset{
    scale to letter height/.style={
        x={height("#1")}, y={height("#1")}, baseline=0pt
    },
}

\begin{document}
    WITH KEY: \tikz[scale to letter height=X]       
    \draw rectangle (1,1) node[right] {\pgfmathparse{height("X")}\pgfmathresult pt};        
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you. Looks like I was not thorough enough when trying out how to determine the height of a piece of text... I'd put the neat example at the top of your answer (or remove the complicated example entirely, because with the `height()` approach it is unnecessarily complex and I would not recommend it as the first solution to anyone coming across this thread in the future).

Comment: @Fritz Thank you for your feedback!